# Chrome Admin Login fails Magento 2

Tags: magento, magento2

Trying to login to `Admin panel(Magento 2)` with Chrome failed with no error message, with Firefox its working fine.

1. Tried different domain name instead of local host
2. Tried disabling system `config -> web -> default cookie settings ->
   use HTTP only`

But no luck...

Answer (score 1):

This was reported to us in GitHub: http://alankent.me/2015/04/25/use-of-localhost-when-installing-magento-2-quick-note/

We could not reproduce the issue in-house but we discovered that Chrome requires at least one period in the host name to set a cookie: http://alankent.me/2015/04/25/use-of-localhost-when-installing-magento-2-quick-note/

Try that and let us know.

Answer (score 0):

You may try changing base_url, in DB, I guess with your ip/127.0.0.1